# Android: Connect to service through Activites, localBinder returns null

Tags: java, android, sockets, service

So, I want to create a TCP socket communication, client runs on Android. In the first Activity I create a Service, no problem. First activity correctly binds, works just fine. Next, I unBind from the Service, then I start the next Activity, when I try to bind to that Service, I get null from my localBinder. Code is below. If anyone has any idea, I'm all ears.

First Activity, works fine.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private EditText getIpAddressEditText;
    private String IpAddress;
    private Socket socket;
    private boolean mIsBound;
    private SocketService mService;
    private EditText ipAddressEditText;
    private Intent theIntent;
    private ProgressDialog mDialog;
    private BufferedWriter out;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        theIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SocketService.class);
        getIpAddressEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.get_ip_address_edit_text);
    }

    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;

            mService = binder.getService();
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            mService = null;
        }
    };

    public void OnConnectToServerButtonClick(View view) {
        IpAddress = getIpAddressEditText.getText().toString();

        theIntent.putExtra("IPADDRESS", IpAddress);
        startService(theIntent);
        doBindService();
        new GetServerSocket().execute();
    }

    private void ConnectToServer() {
        socket = mService.getSocket();

        if (socket.isConnected()) {
            SendMessageToServer("HELLO SERVER");
            doUnbindService();

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,GpsInterfaceActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            doUnbindService();
            stopService(theIntent);
        }
    }

    public void OnGetIpFromSmsButtonClick(View view) {
    }

    private void doBindService() {
        bindService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SocketService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        mIsBound = true;
    }

    private void doUnbindService() {
        if (mIsBound) {
            // Detach our existing connection.
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mIsBound = false;
        }
    }

    public class GetServerSocket extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        public ProgressDialog progDailog;

        public GetServerSocket() {}

        private int a = 0;

        @Override
        public String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            while ( a < 60) {
                try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            a++;

            if (mService != null) {
                socket = mService.getSocket();

                if (socket.isConnected()) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            ConnectToServer();
        }
    }

    public void SendMessageToServer(String string) {
        try {
            out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
            out.write(string);
            out.flush();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Second Activity:

```
public class GpsInterfaceActivity extends Activity {
    private SocketService mService;

    private Socket socket;
    private BufferedWriter out;
    private String[] list = new String[11];

    private String DeviceId;
    private String DeviceStatus;
    private String DeviceTTFF;
    private String DeviceNumberOfSatellites;
    private String DeviceSpeed;
    private String DeviceCourseOverGround;
    private String DeviceAltitude;
    private String DeviceLongitude;
    private String DeviceLatitude;
    private String DeviceNetworkStatus;
    private String DeviceEnergykStatus;

    private TextView ttffEditText;
    private TextView satellitesEditText;
    private TextView speedEditText;
    private TextView courseOverGroundEditText;
    private TextView networkStatusEditText;
    private TextView deviceStatusEditText;
    private TextView energyStatusEditText;

    private ProgressBar energyProgressBar;

    private boolean mIsBound = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gps_interface);

        deviceStatusEditText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.deviceStatusTextView);
        ttffEditText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ttff_edit_text);
        satellitesEditText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.satellites_edit_text);
        speedEditText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.speed_edit_text);
        courseOverGroundEditText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.course_over_ground_edit_text);

        networkStatusEditText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.network_status_edit_text);
        energyStatusEditText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.energy_status_text_view);

        energyProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.energy_proccess_bar);

        doBindService();

        if (mService != null) {
            socket = mService.getSocket();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection Lost", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        new IncomingData().execute();

        SendMessageToServer("HELLO SERVER");
    }

    private ServiceConnection mConnectionn = new ServiceConnection() {

        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;

            mService = binder.getService();
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            mService = null;
        }
    };

    private void InputStreamTokenizer(String input) {
        if (input.contains("DEVICE")) {
            try {

                list = input.split(";");

                DeviceId = list[0];
                DeviceStatus = list[1];
                DeviceTTFF = list[2];
                DeviceNumberOfSatellites = list[3];
                DeviceSpeed = list[4];
                DeviceCourseOverGround = list[5];
                DeviceAltitude = list[6];
                DeviceLongitude = list[7];
                DeviceLatitude = list[8];
                DeviceNetworkStatus = list[9];
                DeviceEnergykStatus = list[10];

                deviceStatusEditText.setText(DeviceStatus);
                ttffEditText.setText(DeviceTTFF);
                satellitesEditText.setText(DeviceNumberOfSatellites);
                speedEditText.setText(DeviceSpeed);
                courseOverGroundEditText.setText(DeviceCourseOverGround);

                networkStatusEditText.setText(DeviceNetworkStatus);
                energyStatusEditText.setText(DeviceEnergykStatus);


            } catch (Exception e){}

            }
    }

    public void SendMessageToServer(String string) {
        try {
            out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
            out.write(string);
            out.flush();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void doBindService() {
        bindService(new Intent(GpsInterfaceActivity.this, SocketService.class), mConnectionn, Context.BIND_ADJUST_WITH_ACTIVITY);
        mIsBound = true;
    }

    private void doUnbindService() {
        if (mIsBound) {
            // Detach our existing connection.
            unbindService(mConnectionn);
            mIsBound = false;
        }
    }

    public class IncomingData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        public BufferedReader input;
        public String read = null;
        public int time = 0;

        public IncomingData() {}

        @Override
        public String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

                while (input.ready()) {
                    read = input.readLine();
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e){
            }
            return read;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(String input) {
            if (input != null) {
                InputStreamTokenizer(input);
            }

            new IncomingData().execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Service:

```
public class SocketService extends Service {
    Socket s;
    String IpAddress;
    Intent intent;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return myBinder;
    }

    public Socket getSocket() {
        return s;
    }

    private final IBinder myBinder = new LocalBinder();

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public SocketService getService() {
            return SocketService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        s = new Socket();
    }

    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId){
        super.onStart(intent, startId);

        IpAddress = intent.getStringExtra("IPADDRESS");

        new Thread(new SocketThread()).start();
    }

    public class SocketThread implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(IpAddress);
                s = new Socket(serverAddr, 8080);
            } catch (SocketException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly do You get null in second activity? Are you sure, that the service is running at second activity?

Comment: mService = binder.getService();  here i get null, so it means, the service is disconnected, but i don't know why. Maybe i need to pass through the intent, my serviceConnection object, and bind to it?

Comment: Could you provide more details (expecially doBindService(), onStartCommand(), onBind() and binder itself from Service)? Looks like your service stopped after you disconnected in first activity.

Comment: I just updated every code, hope it helps.

Comment: For me that code works fine. Currently, I'm able to observe the following issue: you set mIsBound = true just after bindService() call, but actual binding will happen only after onServiceConnected() callback (e.g. call SendMessageToServer() in onCreate() will always fail with NPE). Do You observe any logs related to SocketService (e.g. like service stopped or smth like that)?

Comment: I can't find any logCat information, it streams a huge amount of information every second, impossible to catch smth like service stuff.

Comment: I don't know, what did i do, but now it works :) maybe OnStartCommand, and START_STICKY was the solution. Thanks for your help!